# Record team call with a bot

Tags: microsoft-teams

I love what MS is doing with MS Teams so decided to get rid of Slack, Trello and rest to use Teams, Planner, Sway aggregated in one place.

But call recording during conference calls is still missing there, so trying to come up with a nice way to handle this problem. Hope you guys at MS Teams notice this and advice upon how to do this.

Our first idea was to implement a bot who would receive "/capture-call" message and somehow navigate the video&sound streams to the file on the system, then upload it to the chat.

One way to access these streams is bot being able to somehow physically having a window with a call and capturing the video and audio with SnagIt for example or other capturing tool. Sophisticated but may work.

*preferrable* Another is implementing a nice Bot API so that bot recognizes when being in a call and is able to capture and then upload record to the programmed location(chat, OneDrive)

Hope to see your ideas.

Comment: This really belongs on the [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/16993519-recording-of-video-meetings). The ability recording meetings is in development and was demoed at Ignite just a few days ago: [see this post for more info](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams-Ignite-Blog/MVP-Live-Blog-Understanding-meetings-in-Microsoft-Teams/ba-p/111703)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Teams currently does not support a way for bots to capture audio/video/meeting streams, but it's definitely on the road map. It is a very good scenario!